# What happens to shared memory if one of the process sharing the memory is killed?

Tags: windows, memory, shared-memory

I was working on shared memory and this question came in my mind so thought of asking from experts:

1. What happens to the shared memory if one of the process sharing the memory is killed? What happens if we do hard-kill rather than normal-kill?
2. Is it dependent on the mechanism we use for shared memory?

If it matters, I am working on Windows.

Comment: The OS *should* cleanup all resources (handles, sockets, shm, memory, etc) *that it controls* irregardless of how the process is terminated. Techniques that are outside the OS may not have this protection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided at least one other thread in another process has an open handle to the file mapping, I would expect the shared memory to remain intact.

Comment: It means another process would be able to use the shared memory block irrespective of the state of other process(es)? In other words, process will not have any inter dependency in accessing shared memory block?

Comment: The shared memory doesn't impose concurrency controls; it's up to the processes/threads to ensure safe access.  Often you'd use a mutex object for this.  If the process holding the mutex croaks the mutex gets into abandoned state as reported by others.